# Can we use finite combination of factorials, surds and floor function on a combination of single number, say 4 to form every number?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, exponentiation, factorial, ceiling-and-floor-functions

So the title is much pretty much the question, one thing to note that is you strictly have to use
factorials, surds and floor function.

Edit:

The problem was a little bit ambiguous earlier. So, here are more details:

1. You can use only one number $4$.
2. We can apply any number of factorials and nth roots, and floor functions.
   Also, if it's not possible with factorials, is it with gamma functions?

Comment: Have you made any attempts to solve this problem? If so, where have you run into trouble?

Comment: By surd do you mean the $n$-th root of a number (n>1)? That is, square root or cube root or etc.

Comment: You certainly won't form non-computable or even non-algebraic numbers.

Comment: yeah, that definition.

Comment: @ThunderWolf And also by "every number" do you just mean positive integers? [referring to comment by aschepler]

Comment: Yes, positive inetgrers @coffeemath

Comment: Of the top of my head, I don't see how you could start with $1$ or $2$ and create larger numbers.

Comment: Can one use the $4$ more than once? If so and we can get $1$ using all three of factorial, surd, and floor then that could just be repeated to get the other positive integers, unless you don't allow adding.

Comment: No, @coffeemath, we can use 4 only once. Actually, this problem is self-made and inspired from the "Four Fours challenge", when we observed that factorials make numbers larger and larger, and surds make them smaller and smaller. (If you're wondering how I know this, the OP and I are friends and made this problem together.)

Comment: This seems like more of a combinatorics question.

Comment: Very closely related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24964/repeated-factorials-and-repeated-square-rooting

Comment: That link is helpful @GerryMyerson!